# Graylog: среднее за период времени

Tags: graylog

Возникла необходимость посчитать среднее количество сообщений в graylog за период времени.
На скриншоте в виде таблицы выведено количество сообщений за час. Вопрос как уже из этих данных посчитать и вывести в дашборд например, среднее количество за 3 часа?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. нужно что-то вроде avg(count(request_id))

Answer (score 0):

Установите Rollup intervel 3 часа вместо 1 часа как сейчас установлено у вас.